# Scala stream iterate and memory management

Tags: scala, garbage-collection, scala-collections, scala-streams

I have this code:

```
val res = Stream // launch the real computation, which alternates E and M steps, updating the computation state
  .iterate(initCompState)(Base.emIteration)
  .take(nIteration)
  .last
```

The idea is to provide an initial state `initCompState`, a function that generates a new state from the previous one, run this for `nIterations` and get the final result.

I am not interrested in the intermediary states, and would like them to be garbage collected as soon as they are not needed. From what I read online, `Stream` retains values when they are recursively defined, which is not the case here.

Is my implementation correct and are the intermediate states between the `initCompState` and `res` garbage collected as soon as the next state in the stream has been computed ?

Comment: Rather use `Iterator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stream` is `IterableAgain`, which means, that it will keep all the elements you iterate through in case you want to see them again.

`Iterator` is more appropriate in your case, you can scan through it once, so, it discards each element as soon as you look at it. It does not have `last` though, so, you'd have to implement it yourself with something like

```
 iterator.foldLeft(Option.empty[Int])((_, n) => Some(n))
```

Alternatively, just implement your iterations recursively:

```
 @tailrec
 def iterate(iters: Int, state: State = initCompState): State = if(iters == 0)
   state 
 else 
   iterate(iters - 1, Base.emIteration(state))

 val result = iterate(nIteration)
```

Comment: So, when they said that you should use def instead of val to avoid keeping all the stream in memory, that mean keeping it after it is evaluated. In both cases, during evaluation the entire set of computed values is kept ?

Comment: I don't know who said that ... and why :)

Comment: According to the [Scala doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html) a `Stream` is memoized only as long as something holds on to the head. Using `def` is one way to avoid that. So the real question is: Does `Stream.iterate()()` hold on to its head if the only thing returned is the final iteration? (Which, BTW, can be directly indexed rather than `take(n).last`).

Comment: @jwvh it does ... The code iterating through the stream has no way of knowing whether or not someone is holding the reference to the head, so it has to keep all elements around that it's going through. Later on, as the reference is discarded, those memoized elements go with it (provided, they are not referenced from other objects).